# Matlab Connected Components that touch the Margin

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am writing a matlab script in order to extract lungs from CT images. In order to remove the background from the image, I need to detect the components that touch the margins of the image and then remove it. How can I perform so once I've found the connected components in the image ?

An example is the image below.

[image]

I would like to keep only the inner white part of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [imclearborder](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imclearborder.html) function.

Comment: `imclearborder` is the correct approach.  Simply input your binary image into the function and it returns an outpt where all of the pixels that are connected to the border, as well as any areas that touch these border pixels are removed.